# DB2 V10.5 db2setup hangs on ppc64

Tags: freeze, db2-luw

When using the db2setup (Wizard) to install a new version of DB2 V10.5.0.3 (or the universal fixpack V10.5.7) the installer appears to hang near the end of the Create DB2 Administration task. There is a das directory created in the /home/dasusrX directory but it has no visible files. The logs show no errors. Manually trying to create the DAS also hangs using dascrt -u dasusrX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the console where I launched the db2setup I found I needed to enter the dasusrX password a couple of times. There is no prompt displayed. I believe the system also hangs during the Configuring DB2 instances task and luckily I used the same password for other users so I entered it there as well to complete the install.

I figured this out running the dascrt -d -u dasusrX and saw it hung at the su dasusrX -c /bin/pwd command and when I tried that command manually, it propmted for the dasusrX password. This may be a unique situation for our server set up as root is accessible only via sudo -i so perhaps in other situations there would be no prompt for dasusrX password when using su as root.

Comment: The install also hangs at the very end trying to Configure the DB2 Instances so I reinstalled without creating the instance and did that manually later.